# Some data lost while passing std::vector as in/out reference parameter

Tags: c++, parameter-passing, stdvector

I'm having trouble transferring some data contained in a vector between my functions. The situation is as follows:

```
void generateObjects(std::vector<MyClass> &objects)
{
    objects.clear();
    //Fill objects vector
    std::vector<MyClass> p;

    //This 4-line pattern is repeated a number of times to generate all objects and store them in variable 'objects'
    p.clear();
    generateSomeOfTheObjects(p); //p is again passed by ref. in/out parameter
    for(uint j = 0; j < p.size(); p++){
        objects.push_back(p[j]);
    }

    //Print some members of the objects - works fine
    for(uint i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++){
        printf("%f ",objects[i].mymember->myElm);
    }
}

int main()
{
   std::vector<MyClass> objects;
   generateObjects(objects);
   //Print size of vector - size is correct it is the same as it is in generateObjects func
   printf("%lu\n",objects.size());
   //Again print members of the objects - some members are retained after the function call, some are lost. 
   //The one below doesn't work, mymember is a pointer to another object and its member myElm seems not initialized.
   for(uint i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++){
       printf("%f ",objects[i].mymember->myElm);
   }
   //Here I need to pass the objects to another read-only function
   ...
}
```

I have searched the internet for similar cases and actually found many, but I couldn't apply the same fixes to my code. I'm trying to reach a member of an object pointed to by a member of a MyClass instance (objects[i].mymember->myElm) What possibly am I missing here?

Comment: You'll need to show the code that fills the vector. What you have here looks fine.

Comment: What data members are in `MyClass`?

Comment: Why are you clearing `objects`, making a new `vector p`, filling it and then copying it into `objects`?

Comment: I have updated the code as you said, hope it is clear now. The code is not mine, and it is kind of messy so I had to simplify.

Comment: @guenis, For your reference, [Rule of Three](http://www.tomshardware.com/news/laser-pulse-HDD-Thomas-Ostler-magnetic-field-platter,14654.html). It might be the problem, it might not be, but that will help if it is. It's most likely the problem if your class allocates memory in the constructor for `mymember`, frees it in the destructor, and has no (correct) copy(/move) constructor/assignment operator.

Comment: An easy way to achieve Rule of Three correctness is to avoid it by using smart pointers. [Proof your code works if `MyClass` is properly implemented](http://ideone.com/upAfE)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the error lies in the implementation of `MyClass`. I'd say that this class contains some pointer that is initialized with the address of a local variable, so when you return from some of the functions that pointer points to a destroyed object.

That would *undefined behavior* but it *may* work by chance. When you return from the first function, the stack memory is finally overwritten and your data is lost.

**UPDATE:** Thanks to the insight by @chris in the comments below, the most likely reason is that your `MyClass` does not have a copy constructor, but it does have a pointer member.

Something like this:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    Member *mymember;

    MyClass()
    {
        mymember = new Member;
    }
    ~MyClass()
    {
        delete mymember;
    }
};
```

Now what happens if you use the compiler generated default copy constructor (or the copy operator)?

```
void foo()
{
    MyClass a;
    {
        MyClass b(a);
    }
    //a.mymember is no longer valid
}
```

Both `a` and `b` share the same pointer `mymember`, so when one of them is destroyed, the `mymember` is deleted and the other one holds a dangling pointer.

That's why we have the **rule of three**. It states:

> Whenever you define a non-default destructor, you most likely will want also a non-default copy-constructor and a non-default copy-operator.

Now you have to decide if you want to share the ownership of the `mymember` or if you want to copy it. The first one is best done with smart pointers (`shared_ptr`) and the second one with deep copy.

For example, deep copy:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    Member *mymember;

    MyClass()
    {
        mymember = new Member;
    }
    MyClass(const MyClass &c)
    {
        mymember = new Member(c.mymember);
    }
    MyClass &operator=(const MyClass &c)
    {
        if (this != &c) //be aware of self-copy
        {
            delete mymember;
            mymember = new Member(c.mymember);
        }
        return *this;
    }
    ~MyClass()
    {
        delete mymember;
    }
};
```

And with shared pointers:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    std::shared_ptr<Member> mymember; //or boost::shared_ptr if old compiler

    MyClass()
        :mymember(new Member)
    {
    }
    //no custom-made destructor -> no rule of 3
};
```

Comment: I was thinking rule of three with my comment, but we won't know without the class definition.

Comment: @chris: You are right. The objects are _copied_ from `p` to `objects`, so a default copy constructor could cause this problems. That is actually more likely.

Comment: Just depends if it's holding data or creating it, really.

Comment: I'm not very experienced with C++, but chris I think you found where the problem is, the class is missing the copy constructor

Comment: @rodrigo, Feel free to edit in the rule of three and cover both bases. Based on the question's code, that's about the best answer you can get.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps unrelated to you question, but this:

```
void generateObjects(std::vector<MyClass> &objects)
{
  objects.clear();
  std::vector<MyClass> p;
  p.clear();

  generateSomeOfTheObjects(p);
  for(uint j = 0; j < p.size(); p++){
      objects.push_back(p[j]);
  }

  for(uint i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++){
      printf("%f ",objects[i].mymember->myElm);
  }
}
```

Is the same as this:

```
void generateObjects(std::vector<MyClass> &objects)
{
  objects.clear();
  generateSomeOfTheObjects(objects);
  std::reverse(objects.begin(), objects.end()); 
  for(uint i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {
      printf("%f ",objects[i].mymember->myElm);
  }
}
```

You copy issues, as @rodrigo mentioned, is that you are not doing deep copies with your copy constructors.

Comment: As I said it is not my code, and so it is so messy I just like to fix it asap. But thank you for the help